# Displaying image on button click event in a java project

Tags: java

I'm doing a Java project on Netbeans. And I'm stuck not knowing how to add My own image into the code. It's not working, no matter where I put the image. This sounds ridiculous but it really got me stuck.

I tried to display the image using label on a jframe, but it's not working properly, because my image which i wanna display will be generated @same event of button click and afterwards it should be displayed in the same window.

How can I display images for a particular button click event in a java project, with NetBeans?

Comment: What netbeans version are you using?

Comment: Look up "How to use labels"